Climbing plant for a kitchen window
I like to keep plants in the shady north facing window of my kitchen. Pathos, snake plants, and a stunted Himalayan Ivy live there now.
Unfortunately they need too much room. Time for a change.  I have hung an ornamental chain in the window as a trellis, and I want some climbers to live under and grow over it.
What plants would work well for me?

live in a shaded, north facing window in the Northern hemisphere
live on a 5 inch / 13cm  window sill - round pots or a rectangular planter
climb a trellis and stay reasonably close to it
offer a degree of privacy when grown in
slower growth is preferred, I don't want to fuss with it too often

Here is a picture of the Old Situation during the brightest part of the day. The curtains are now completely gone.


A Pelargonium will climb slowly and be almost impossible to kill. But  so would most other plants - IMHO the question needs additional constrains.
